# Java Swing: JScrollPane dosen't expand to fit JPanel in it

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have a `JTabel` and I want to add it to a `JScrollPane`. But the `JScrollPane` has very small size. I have tried to put the table to `JPanel`(have sized) and then put the `JPanel` to `JScrollPane` but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
 static public class PnGiaoDich extends JPanel{
    public PnGiaoDich(){
        //size & background
        setPreferredSize( new Dimension(1050, 435));
        setBackground(new Color(255,255,255));

        //layout
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints(); 

        //create table
        String[] columnNames = {"Ngày giao dịch",
                    "Loại gio dịch | Mô tả",
                    "Tình trạng",
                    "Số tiền"
                    };

        Object[][] data = {
                        {"","","",""},
                        {"","","",""},
                        {"","","",""},
                        {"","","",""}
                        };

        JTable table = new JTable(data,columnNames);
        TableColumn column = null;
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(150);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(525);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(150);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(150);

        // create table to put into JScrollPane
        JPanel pnTable = new JPanel();
        pnTable.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
        pnTable.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        pnTable.add(table);
        //Add panel to JScrollPane
        JScrollPane scrollpn = new JScrollPane(pnTable);
        //table.setFillsViewportHeight(true); 

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        c.insets = new Insets(20,20,20,20);
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        add(scrollpn,c);

       //
    }
}
```

But if I post these code to main JFrame, it work properly.

Here is entire of my code:  [enter link description here](https://www.codepile.net/pile/VvWL1PeO)

The image of my JScrollPane:

[image]

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) `setPreferredSize( .. );` Don't do that. If it's necessary to manually set a preferred size, override the method. But I can see no good reason to do that here, and it is probably counter productive. 3) `..PnGiaoDich extends JPanel` Don't extend GUI components unless changing functionality or adding new functionality that is directly relevant to the component.

Comment: thanks you for your help. I'm new to Java form so there a lot of thing i don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, let's just have a walk through...

```
setPreferredSize( new Dimension(1050, 435));
```

... try and avoid doing this.  If you "have" to, then override `getPreferredSize` instead, as `setPreferredSize` is a vulnerability to your "stable" UI

```
setBackground(new Color(255,255,255));

//layout
setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints(); 

//create table
String[] columnNames = {"Ngày giao dịch",
            "Loại gio dịch | Mô tả",
            "Tình trạng",
            "Số tiền"
            };

Object[][] data = {
                {"","","",""},
                {"","","",""},
                {"","","",""},
                {"","","",""}
                };

JTable table = new JTable(data,columnNames);
TableColumn column = null;
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(150);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(525);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(150);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(150);
```

Okay, not bad so far...

```
// create table to put into JScrollPane
JPanel pnTable = new JPanel();
pnTable.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
pnTable.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
pnTable.add(table);
//Add panel to JScrollPane
JScrollPane scrollpn = new JScrollPane(pnTable);
//table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
```

And ... what?  Why add the `JTable` to a `JPanel`, which is using a `FlowLayout`, which then gets added the `JScrollPane`?  Why not just add the `JTable` to the `JScrollPane` itself?

Also, doing this, you're going to screw with the ability of the `JTable` and `JScrollPane` to talk to each other and determine when the scrolling should take place.

```
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 1;
c.gridwidth = 2;
c.insets = new Insets(20,20,20,20);
c.weightx = 1;
c.weighty = 1;
c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
add(scrollpn,c);
```

`c.gridwidth = 2;`?  While it's probably not going to have an effect, it raises more questions about why?

## Solution...

Okay, after mucking about with the constraints and removing the extra `JPanel`, the problem comes down to

```
setPreferredSize( new Dimension(1050, 435));
```

and probably isn't helped by `pnTable.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));`

I basically stripped the code back to the following, which "basically" works...

```
static public class PnGiaoDich extends JPanel {

    public PnGiaoDich() {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        //layout
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        //create table
        String[] columnNames = {"Ngày giao dịch",
            "Loại gio dịch | Mô tả",
            "Tình trạng",
            "Số tiền"
        };

        Object[][] data = {
            {"", "", "", ""},
            {"", "", "", ""},
            {"", "", "", ""},
            {"", "", "", ""}
        };

        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(150);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(525);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(150);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(150);

        //Add panel to JScrollPane
        table.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
        JScrollPane scrollpn = new JScrollPane(table);
        //table.setFillsViewportHeight(true); 

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.insets = new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20);
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        add(scrollpn, c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi MadProgrammer! This is entire of my code https://www.codepile.net/pile/VvWL1PeO  I tried to fix my code like your solution but It didn't worked. That maybe the PnGiaoDich was added to JFrame so I post entire my code for u.